# How to update hashmap value based on a conditional statement

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I need help updating the value of my HashMap. The idea is that the user will input the Rover Direction as N. The user then inputs the behaviour as L (for left). The move_left method then updates the Hashmap key "D" to equal "W" instead of the "N" which the user inputs. However, this piece of code is not updating it to "W". Any help would be great. I am an absolute beginner, so any recommendations would be great!

```
def rover_direction
  puts " \n Please input the direction which the rover is facing 
 (N,E,S,W):    "
 user_input = gets.chomp.upcase
 @direction = {"D" => user_input}
end

def rover_behaviour
  puts " \n Please input the behaviour of the rover(L,R & M):    "
  input = gets.chomp.upcase
  @behaviour = input.scan /\w/

  if @behaviour[0] == "L" 
    move_left
  elsif @behaviour[0] == "R" 
    move_right
  elsif @behaviour[0] == "M"
    move_forward
  end
end

#move rover left as per behaviour input
def move_left
  if @direction[0] == "N"  
    @direction.update("D") { |key, user_input| user_input == W }
  elsif @direction[0] == "W"
    @direction.update("D") { |key, user_input| user_input == "S" }
  elsif @direction[0] == "S"
    @direction.update("D") { |key, user_input| user_input == "E" }
  elsif @direction[0] == "E"
    @direction.update("D") { |key, user_input| user_input == "N" }
  end
end
```

Comment: _"any recommendations would be great"_ – start by indenting your code properly ;-)

Comment: Why are you storing the direction within a hash, i.e. `@direction = {'D' => 'W'}` instead of just `@direction = 'W'`?

Comment: Try using `case` to break out multiple branches instead of a whole heap of `if` statements. Also Ruby does have `else if`, it's `elsif`. Although there's many ways to indent your code, preferences and styles vary, the way it's done here is not one of them and is total chaos. Fix that first to make sure your program is structured correctly.